# Pass a class to other page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 page

```
<a href="http://example.com/Rank1?page=tab-1">Rank1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/Rank2?page=tab-2">Rank2</a>
<a href="http://example.com/Rank3?page=tab-3">Rank3</a>
```

So when i click on a link, i need add class "current" in the new page just in the correct element. (I have the code in the new page to swap between tabs working fine). The tables in the new page:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li id="divtab-1" class="button tab-link" data-tab="tab-1">Rank1</li>
    <li id="divtab-2" class="button tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Rank2</li>
    <li id="divtab-3" class="button tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Rank3</li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">Rank1</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Rank2</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Rank3</div>
</div>
```

The actual code in the new page addclass 'current' o remove class 'current' on click. THX!

```
    jQuery( function( $ ){
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
      var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

      $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
      $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

      $(this).addClass('current');
      $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })
  })
  var url = window.location.href;
  var queryString = url.split("?")[1];
  var paramValue = queryString.split("=")[1];
  $("#div"+paramValue).addClass('current');
      $("#"+paramValue).addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: I suspect you're thinking about this the wrong way.  When navigating from one page to another, the first page doesn't modify anything on the second page.  Each page runs in isolation.  Focus on your second page.  When that page loads, what information do you need to detect in order to determine what you want to do?  It *sounds like* you're looking to read the URL when the page loads and modify some elements' classes based on that URL.

Comment: I edited the post. I think you are correct. I want to click in page 1 link Rank2 (link to page 2), and then, in page 2 addClass "current" in "li.button.tab-link" tab-2 & "tab-content" tab-2 to display the info.

Comment: What's the relation between the first links with the tabs? If you click `http://example.com/Rank2/` you need to add `current` to all `tab-2`? Then why the `.tab-link` aren't the anchors?

Comment: Well, actually i use a code that focus "data-tab" and #tab_id. And its working fine, but i dont know how to edit to work with url parameters or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not doing all this in plain JS then use query params:

change urls in first page like below :

```
<a href="http://example.com?page=Rank1">Rank1</a> 
<a href="http://example.com?page=Rank2">Rank2</a>
<a href="http://example.com?page=Rank3">Rank3</a>
```

Access this url params in second page :

```
var url = window.location.href;
var queryString = url.split("?")[1];
var paramValue = queryString.split("=")[1]; // would print Rank1 or Rank2 or Rank3 based on url param
```

Once you get value of page name, do your Tab logic as per you coding

Comment: Oh! Thx! i think i am so close, I edited the code with ur advice. Now when u click in the link show the content but i am trying to add "current" in ul.li as well. Can u give a hand?

Comment: Ok Vipul, i added a new id to the ul.li elements. Do you know something cleaner? check my code please. And thx!